# alanning:role, importing issue in angular2-meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, roles, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I have used `alanning:role` package by **meteor**, the **Roles** are working fine but the problem is I am getting warnings that `"Cannot find name 'Roles"`.

Kindly help me with this problem. I have searched it everywhere.

Some people import it like `"import { Roles } from 'alanning:roles';"`

I have also tried this but still getting errors on this... 
Please help me and please don't commit it as in **"asked issue"**. 
I am searching this issue from past two days, but I got no answer, please suggest me any help or please resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it `import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';`

Comment: I have tried it but its not working, the package is installed in meteor pakcages file, but its still showing that its not installed, but its working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error you are facing is typing error. Its a meteor package and to notify typescript that your are using it your have to tell it by importing it.I had faced same kind of issue. actually you forgot to import

```
 import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
```

in your collection file or publish file. Import it in your collection & publish file you will not face this typo error.

Next thing if you are facing error  `Cannot find module 'meteor/alanning:roles'` after importing that means meteor don't have   definition for that package in `typings.d.ts`. Some of the packages don't have type definition file yet. you have to create your own typescript definition in typings.d.ts file or if you have new angular 2 meteor boilerplate that have @typings folder. just add this code in that file

```
declare module "meteor/alanning:roles" {
  export module Roles {
    function userIsInRole(id?: any,value?: any): boolean{  }
    function addUsersToRoles(id?: any,value?: any): boolean{ }
  }
}
```

for other packages that give similar kind of error you can create your own definition.

Comment: Before importing I am getting this error " Cannot find name 'Roles'. " and after importing I am getting this error "  Cannot find module 'meteor/alanning:roles'. ". I know that without importing I can use this package but how can you expect that I am not importing it? 
I have already tried " alanning:Roles " package with import it and without importing it.
its working fine without importing, but I am getting an error without importing it, so that's why I want to import this package.

Comment: @Habib M.Farooq i was expecting this because you were saying Cannot find name 'Roles instead of Cannot find module 'meteor/alanning:roles. first on comes if you do not import Roles and second one comes if you don't have definition of that package in typings.d.ts . Anyway no problem i have updated my answer for you :) check it once

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer...
It worked and everything working fine... Thanks bro.. :)

Comment: Plz Don't forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking right sign, for people who have the same problem in the future! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to import meteor packages in typescript without writing your own declarations. Most of the types are defined here

> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types
>   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/meteor

Install NPM module that has types defined.

```
meteor npm install --save @types/meteor-roles
```

Import the types in your modules

```
import { } from '@types/meteor-roles';
```

Now, you can use Roles type for methods like addUsersToRoles() etc.